# AZIMUTH reading too sensitive on Sony Xperia phone updated with android OS 4.3 even with low pass filter

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am troubled  with  the too sensitive sensor reading   issue with SONY Xperia phone loaded with android OS 4.3 .

My compass orientation and azimuth reading has no issue at all with Samsung Note 3 or  S3 galaxy even without low pass filter algorithm .

When loaded to the SONY xperia phone Z series , the compass kept spinning non-stop even when I have applied the low pass filter algorithm ,something I could not understand was it due to recent os update 4.3 or the sensor in sony phone was just far too sensitive?

I have even apply a seek bar to enable the value of ALPHA to be adjusted varies from 1 to 0 and that still does not help at all .

protected float[] lowPass( float[] input, float[] output ) {
    if ( output == null ) return input;

```
for ( int i=0; i<input.length; i++ ) {
    output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
}
return output;
```

}

Any help or comment are very much appreciated.

Comment: What specific Android sensor type are you listening to?

Comment: default accelerometer and magnetometer sensor , standard official android reference to obtain azimuth , work on all the samsung phone but not SONY Xperia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which sensors you're working with (e.g. Acceleration + Magnetic Field), I've had sensitivity issues in the past. The composite sensors (the suitable one in this case might be RotationVector) produce a much better output, especially for azimuth, in that they integrate several of the sensor measurements together.

Comment: Hello Jranalli, I have rewrite the code as per your suggestion using the composite sensor via rotation vector  , the problem seemed to have resolved , thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hello Jranalli , just one more question ,when I look at the SONY sensor listing , apparently they are manufactured by the famous INvensense , just wonder why the proprietary algorithm or hardware base algorithem  incorporated could not function , I still not sure if the rotation vector does function like it should or not in term of orientation bearing? Tested on samsung phone having STMirco sensor , seemed much better response than SONY ?

Comment: I'm not really an expert on the individual hardware to say why one is better than another.  It's easy enough to establish whether the measurements are accurate using analog devices (a compass/a protractor and level).  That's the only testing I've done on my app.

Comment: Compass are notoriously inaccurate with relative to the magnetic north or true north , any sensor in the mobile phone are far more accurate , as i need my app to be able to be sensitive to the environment change with accuracy round up to +/- 0.01 degree, it is imperative that the logic or software algorithm capable of doing that. I would explore more on the android synthetic sensor like rotation vector  , various sources have indicated that some kind of fusion sensor logic is included  and it is all depend on phone manufacture how they interpret and incorporate into the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback ,

I do apply the suggested default acceleration + magnetic filed , and then the usual get orientation to obtain the azimuth , the funny thing is it works on all the samsung phone which I guess they properly apply some form of algorithm using the Invensense sensor , whereas in sony phone , such algorithm may be different or not presence .I will try the rotationvector to see if this solve the issue or not especially  I also noticed the magnetic reading is also a bit strange on the sony phone on horizontal plane.

App will ensure tgat   the phone is to be place in horizontal position before taking reading as such I think gyroscope input may not be needed, although this may be a solution to help to improve the raw sensor data processing as long as it works on SONY.

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

```
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            //valuesAccelerometer = (float[]) event.values.clone();
            valuesAccelerometer = lowPass(event.values.clone(), valuesAccelerometer);
        /*
         * for (int i=0;i<3;i++){ valuesAccelerometer[i]=event.values[i] ;
         *
         * }
         */
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            //valuesMagneticField = (float[]) event.values.clone();
            valuesMagneticField = lowPass(event.values.clone(), valuesMagneticField);
        /*
         * for (int i=0;i<3;i++){ valuesMagneticField[i]=event.values[i];
         *
         * }
         */
            break;

    }
    if (valuesAccelerometer != null & valuesMagneticField != null) {

        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(matrixR, matrixI,
                valuesAccelerometer, valuesMagneticField);

        //  txt_read.setText(String.valueOf(success));

        if (success) {
            SensorManager.getOrientation(matrixR, matrixValues);
            azimuth = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[0]);
            // azimuth=matrixValues[0];
            float vaz = new Float(azimuth);
            //  float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);

            pitch = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[1]);
            roll = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[2]);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                valuesMagneticField[i] = event.values[i];
            }
```